# Ragged Tensors have no len() after conversion to Tensor

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras, ragged-tensors

I am training a deep learning model on stacks of images with variable dimensions. `(Shape = [Batch, None, 256, 256, 1])`, where None can be variable.

I use  `tf.RaggedTensor.merge_dimsions(0,1)` to convert the ragged Tensor to a shape of `[None, 256, 256, 1]` to run into a pretrained keras CNN model.

However, using the KerasLayer API results in the following error: `TypeError: the object of type 'RaggedTensor' has no len()`

When I apply `.merge_dimsions` outside of the KerasLayer and pass the tensors to the same pretrained model I do not get this error.

```py
import tensorflow as tf

# Synthetic Data Pipeline
def synthetic_gen():
  varShape = tf.random.uniform((), minval=1, maxval=12, dtype=tf.int32)
  image = tf.random.normal((varShape, 256, 256, 1))
  image = tf.RaggedTensor.from_tensor(image, ragged_rank=1)
  yield image

ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(synthetic_gen, output_signature=(tf.RaggedTensorSpec(shape=(None, 256, 256, 1), dtype=tf.float32, ragged_rank=1)))
ds = ds.repeat().batch(8)
print(next(iter(ds)).shape)

# Build Model
inputs = tf.keras.Input(
    type_spec=tf.RaggedTensorSpec(
        shape=(8, None, 256, 256, 1), 
        dtype=tf.float32, 
        ragged_rank=1))

ResNet50 = tf.keras.applications.ResNet50(
    include_top=True, 
    input_shape=(256, 256, 1),
    weights=None)

def merge(x):
  x = x.merge_dims(0, 1)
  return x
x = tf.keras.layers.Lambda(merge)(inputs)
merged_inputs = x
# x = ResNet50(x) # Uncommenting this will result in `model` producing an error when run for inference.

model = tf.keras.Model(inputs, x)

# Run inference
data = next(iter(ds))
model(data).shape # Will be an error if ResNet50 is used
```

Here is a colab notebook that demonstrates the problem. https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1kN78mf4_oNqxWOluV054NlqmakC5msli?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if the following answer or workaround is stable for complex network design. But here are some pointers. The reason you got

```
Ragged Tensors have no len()
```

is because of **ResNet** models, as it expects `tensor` and not `ragged_tensor`. I'm not sure however if the **ResNet(weights=None)** is able to take `ragged_tensor` or not directly. So, if we can convert the ragged data right before the **ResNet** gets fed, maybe it won't complain. Below is the full working code according to this. But please note, there is probably some efficient approach maybe possible.

---

**Data**

```
import tensorflow as tf

# Synthetic Data Pipeline
def synthetic_gen():
  varShape = tf.random.uniform((), minval=1, maxval=12, dtype=tf.int32)
  image = tf.random.normal((varShape, 256, 256, 1))
  image = tf.RaggedTensor.from_tensor(image, ragged_rank=1)
  yield image

ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(synthetic_gen, 
                                    output_signature=(tf.RaggedTensorSpec(
                                        shape=(None, 256, 256, 1), 
                                        dtype=tf.float32, ragged_rank=1
                                        )
                                    )
                                )
ds = ds.repeat().batch(8)
```

### Basic Model

```
# Build Model
inputs = tf.keras.Input(
    type_spec=tf.RaggedTensorSpec(
        shape=(8, None, 256, 256, 1), 
        dtype=tf.float32, 
        ragged_rank=1))

ResNet50 = tf.keras.applications.ResNet50(
    include_top=True, 
    input_shape=(256, 256, 1),
    weights=None)

def merge(x):
  x = x.merge_dims(0, 1)
  return x
```

### Ragged Model

Here we convert `ragged_tensor` to `tensor` before passing the data to **ResNet**.

```
class RagModel(tf.keras.Model):
    def __init__(self):
        super(RagModel, self).__init__()
        # base models 
        self.a = tf.keras.layers.Lambda(merge)
        # convert: tensor = ragged_tensor.to_tensor()
        self.b = tf.keras.layers.Lambda(lambda x: x.to_tensor())
        self.c = ResNet50
    
    def call(self, inputs, training=None, plot=False, **kwargs):
        x = self.a(inputs)
        x = self.b(x) if not plot else x
        x = self.c(x)
        return x
    
    # a helper function to plot 
    def build_graph(self):
        x = tf.keras.Input(type_spec=tf.RaggedTensorSpec(
            shape=(8, None, 256, 256, 1),
            dtype=tf.float32, ragged_rank=1)
        )
        return tf.keras.Model(inputs=[x],
                              outputs=self.call(x, plot=True))
   
x_model = RagModel()
```

### Run

```
data = next(iter(ds)); print(data.shape)
x_model(data).shape 
(8, None, 256, 256, 1)
TensorShape([39, 1000])
```

### Plot

```
tf.keras.utils.plot_model(x_model.build_graph(), 
              show_shapes=True, show_layer_names=True)
```

[image]

```
x_model.build_graph().summary()

Model: "model_1"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_4 (InputLayer)         [(8, None, 256, 256, 1)]  0         
_________________________________________________________________
lambda_2 (Lambda)            (None, 256, 256, 1)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
resnet50 (Functional)        (None, 1000)              25630440  
=================================================================
Total params: 25,630,440
Trainable params: 25,577,320
Non-trainable params: 53,120
_________________________________________________________________
```